# WYSIWYG Rich-text editor converting to markdown Quill.js

Tags: javascript, angular, markdown, wysiwyg

I am trying to implement a WYSIWYG editor in a web app based on Angular and made a POC on then Angular lib based on [Quill](https://quilljs.com/).

The texts are saved in markdown  in the database, then parsed to HTML for the view.

It works fine for text creation, not for text edition as Quill only understands Delta, not markdown.

The few markdown to delta conversion libraries are not maintained and it overcomplicates the process.

Have you tried any WYSIWG editor library in JS that can read markdown ?
Ideas are most welcome !